# EE3 Title url generates differently with Structure when using dot in it

Tags: structure, url, ee3, url-title

When typing title EE3 generates url title automatically but it doesnt generate same as on sturcture url, so post links goes wrong. Had to do manually every time.

Example if I type:

```
My.Title
```

EE3 url generates:

```
my.title
```

but structure url generates:

```
my_title
```

Any fixes?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no real fix for that. For EE2 there was an accessory https://github.com/shoeshine/url_title_match that sort of fixed this. I don't know of any EE3 alternative